# Specify what localizations are being built in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, msbuild, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL project with multiple localizations that are specified in *.resx files and several platform-specific localization files (native for Android and UWP).
This solution is being built using MSBuild. I want to specify languages that will be included in each build. How it can be achieved using MSBuild and standard Xamarin build procedures without modifying *.csproj files before each build?

Comment: Hi，what is your problem? By `multiple localizations`, what do you mean? Can you show some pictures? What do you want to do with the language?

Comment: By multiple localizations I mean that that all texts in applications translated on different languages. These strings are stored in different *.resx files (names something like Texts.resx, Texts.en.resx, Texts.es.resx, Texts.pt-BR.resx, etc.) included in Xamarin.Forms project. I want to build an app that will contain only pt-BR localization. Also I don't  want to modify project for this - all configurations should be made by tweaking MSBuild. How this can be achieved?